# Using output of categorical distribution in Pymc3 as index for selection of down stream parameters

Tags: distributions, categorical-data, function, pymc3

The code that I would like to generate is something like:
I want to have a categorical variable that maps to another value different from the index given by the categorical distribution, and fits as a parameter in the next level

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    gamma = np.ones(3)
    h = pm.Dirichlet("theta", a=gamma)
    lambda_dict = {
      0:4.4,
      1:0.2,
      2:3.1
    }
    lambda_h_i = lambda_dict[h]

    alpha = pm.Exponential('alpha', lam=lambda_h_i)
    alpha_val = pm.Deterministic("alpha_val", alpha - (1/lambda_h_i))
    theta = pm.Beta('theta', alpha=alpha, beta=alpha, observed=data)
```